# what is command to launch on click in Cairo Dock

Tags: icons, shortcuts, 21.04, cairo-dock, cairo

I have installed cairo dock and want to add applications shortcut like "vscode", "terminal", "VLC" etc on the dock. and when i try to add it it is asking for this.

`command to launch on click` I don't know what is this and through out the web There is no single example for this.

and then I need to add icon manually but where are those icons i didn't get. I'm using ubuntu 21.04.

So, my question is how to add app shortcut along with icon to cairo dock.

Comment: why negative rating? I'm unable to add icons from past 2 days. If the one who disliked knows better kindly educate me. I'll delete the question itself if it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you have to do the following:

1. Open some graphical application using menu
2. Wait for the icon to appear in Cairo Dock
3. Make right mouse click on appeared icon in Cairo Dock, select second row of the menu, then click on *Make it a launcher*

[image: Cairo-Dock]

Notes:

- steps 2 and 3 maybe done simpler - you can drag application icon from desktop environment menu and drop it directly to dock.
- Cairo-Dock normally works with deb-packaged applications (with desktop-files, of course), with GUI applications from Ubuntu Make, Snap, FlatPak and any other applications for which you (or some application) created a desktop-launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Comment: Thank you i did this. but, for VSCODE the icon appearing on dock is notepad icon. and for launcher there is a big question mark icon. so for me this method is not working may be I have done some mistakes but i don't know what is that even.

Comment: For reproducible positive result I would recommend to install vscode using Ubuntu Make. Use the following commands to do so - `sudo snap install ubuntu-make --classic; umake ide visual-studio-code`, then reboot. Then execute it for first time using `~/.local/share/umake/bin/visual-studio-code` and pin its icon to Cairo Dock. Or open file-manager in `~/.local/share/applications`, then drag `visual-studio-code.desktop` and drop it to Cairo Dock.